# Release pipeline for Azure Function without app service (For consumption plan)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I was trying to create a release pipleline for azure function app, which I want host under consumption plan hence I don't have an app service created. May I know which template to select for the same. The default template I got have a mandatorty app service plan to be inserted

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found how it works. When you publish the function app from visual studio it will generate a default app service, which you can give in the release pipeline

Comment: function app cannot exist without app service, this question makes no sense

Comment: @4c74356b41It was super not obvious to me that an app service was created implicitly when I created an Azure Function, but I did mine in the portal, so I did see a new app service with a generated name.  Without having seen that, I _also_ wouldn't have known that this existed.  This seems like a very reasonable Q&A to me but if you have complaints, I think an edit of the question or answer might help.